# How to find whole word (with space) from array using Python?

Tags: python

I have an array that is given below. I want to compare users response with this array.

```py
array = ['finance', 'healthcare', 'information technology', 'government', 'textile', 'petroleum']
```

Here is my code.

```
 if str(user_response) in str(array):
    for j in range(array_length):
        if str(user_response) == str(array[j]):
          some code
 else:
     print("give valid answer")
```

If the users response would be  **'information technology'**, then it is working fine. But if the users response would be only **technology**, then it also is consider as an answer. It has to print the `else` message when user will give response like **technology**.

So, how can I match whole word 'information technology' from the array, instead of only 'technology'?

Comment: See what happens if you enter `[` as your `user_response`. It too will match, because you're stringifying the entire array of words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too many `str()` casts all around, making the initial `if` a substring search.

Try

```
array = ['finance', 'healthcare', 'information technology', 'government', 'textile', 'petroleum']

user_response = str(...)  # wherever you get the input from

# If you don't cast `array` to a string, 
# Python will just try to find the string in the list; 
# otherwise it does a substring search.

if user_response in array:
   # ...
else:
   print("Give valid answer")
```